# How to specified a group of object in a dataframe column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the example below, how do I specified  'mansion' under 'h_type', and find its highest price?

(prevent from finding a highest price from the whole data which might include 'aparment')

ie:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'h_type':[aparment,mansion,....],'h_price':[..., ...,...]})
```

```
if df.loc[df['h_type']=='mansion']:  ##<= do not work, 
  aidMax = priceSr.idxmax()
  if  not isnan(aidMax): 
    amaxSr = df.loc[aidMax]
    if amost is None:
      amost = amaxSr.copy()
    else:
      if float(amaxSr['h_price']) > float(amost['h_price']):
        amost = amaxSr.copy()

amost = amost.to_frame().transpose()
print(amost, '\n==========')
```

Comment: There seems to be more than one question in here, please narrow down or re-formulate the question.

Comment: `df = ` would produce a dictionary not a dataframe,,  but it will be rejected as the list contains undefined variables not name strings.

Comment: `if x in df["h_type"]== "mansion":` has no meaning in Python - what is x? What are you trying to do?

Comment: in the real case, i would read from a csv file. however i have already addup  the pd.DataFrame() method for a more clear information.   the part i am confuse about is instead of finding the highest price of the total data, how do i specified it by group

Comment: just check what `type(mansion)` returns and put it on your `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR:

That can be a oneliner:

```py
max_price = df[df["h_price"] == "mansion"]]["h_price"].max()
```

#### Explanation

A little bit of explaining here:

```py
df[df["h_price"] == "mansion"]]
```

That pieces selects all the rows who's column "h_price" value is the maximum.

```py
df[df["h_price"] == "mansion"]]["h_price"]
```

Then, we access the column "h_price" of all the rows.

Finally

```py
df[df["h_price"] == "mansion"]]["h_price"].max()
```

Will return the maximum value for that column (amongs all rows).